# Can someone explain me why it throws an ArgumentOutOfRangeException?

Tags: c#, .net

```
static List<object> JosephusPermutation(List<object> items, int k)
{
  List<object> solution = new List<object>();
  int index = k - 1;
  int len = items.Count;
  int count = 1;
  foreach(object i in items){
    if(index<len){
      solution.Add(items[index]);
      index += k;
    }
    else{
      index = (index - 1) - len * count;
      count++;
    }
  }
  return solution;
}
```

I tried to create a function that takes every k element in the array and get an OutOfRangeException and don't know why it's happening. Can you explain me why these piece of code behaves like these? Appreciate your help!

Comment: I guess your answer is in debugging, please debug your code and understand why index is going beyond length of `items` list

Comment: How many elements are in `List<object> items` and what is the value of `index`?

Comment: items has 8 elements and index is index of first item which should be taken from items and at each iteration it increases by k

Comment: I think you are getting negative values here : `index = (index - 1) - len * count;`

Comment: yes that was intentional. I need to only create solution array with same size like items array using this loop

Comment: A tipp: if using indexing in a `foreach` loop, change it to a `for` loop first. Makes things a lot more readable IMHO.

Comment: This question is not related to Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code. Please remove the according tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the reason:

```
index = (index - 1) - len * count;
```

As soon as `count` is > 1, you're substracting a number bigger than the list length, resulting in a negative index. Removing the `* count` should fix this.